# Upload chunked file using XHR and web workers

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, upload, web-worker

Hi everyone and happy new year :)

I want to upload a file using XHR and web workers, sending chunks of the file and merging at the end. The problem is that the end file is empty, I think that the issue is in the content type of XHR request that will should send a correct "multipart/form-data" (when uploading a chunk), since that PHP print_r($_FILES) returns an empty Array() but in the web worker it's not possible to use FormData(). Help me to resolve this trouble, please :'(

**index.html**

```
<form onsubmit="return false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" type="file">    
    <div id="filedrop">or drop files here</div>
</form>

<script>

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var fileselect = document.getElementById("file");   
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

    var filedrag = document.getElementById("filedrop");      
    filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
    filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
    filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
}, false);

function FileDragHover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
}

function FileSelectHandler(e) {
    FileDragHover(e);

    var blob = e.target.files[0] || e.dataTransfer.files[0];

    worker = new Worker("upload.webworker.js");
    worker.postMessage(blob);

    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    };       
}
</script>
```

**uploadFile.php**

```
<? 

if ($_GET['a'] == "chunk") {
    $target = "upload/" . $_GET['name'] . '-' . $_GET['index'];  
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);  
    sleep(1);
 } else {  
    $target = "upload/" . $_GET['name'];
    $dst = fopen($target, 'wb');
    $slices = (int)$_GET['slices'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $slices; $i++) {
        $slice = $target . '-' . $i;
        $src = fopen($slice, 'rb');
        stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dst);
        fclose($src);
        unlink($slice);
    }

    fclose($dst);
}

?>
```

**upload.webworker.js**

```
function uploadChunk(blob, index, start, end, slices, slices2) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function() {
        slices--;

        if (slices == 0) {
            var xhrMerge = new XMLHttpRequest();            
            xhrMerge.open("POST", "uploadFile.php?a=merge&name=" + blob.name + "&slices=" + slices2);

            xhrMerge.onload = function() {
                self.close();
            };

            xhrMerge.send();
        }
    };

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) self.postMessage(Math.round(100 / e.total * e.loaded)); //this doesn't work o.O
    };

    var chunk = blob.slice(start, end);

    xhr.open("POST", "uploadFile.php?a=chunk&name=" + blob.name + "&index=" + index); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart\/form-data; boundary=--------------------");  
    xhr.send(chunk);
}

self.onmessage = function(e) {
    const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 1024 * 32;

    var blob = e.data,
        start = 0,
        index = 0,
        slices = Math.ceil(blob.size / BYTES_PER_CHUNK),
        slices2 = slices;

    while (start < blob.size) {
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;

        if (end > blob.size) end = blob.size;

        uploadChunk(blob, index, start, end, slices, slices2);

        start = end;
        index++;
    }
};
```

PS: if you want, tell me please how to optimize the upload in general =)

PPS: I'll should take advantages using synchronous ajax requests (only in the web worker) ?

PPPS: and if I to use php://input for reading chunk, it's better ?

Comment: Just curious why you want to use web workers at all here? Uploading is an asynchronous operation, so wouldn't be blocking the UI thread anyway. And your code would be way simpler without it.

Comment: some tutorials explain this as a better method to speed up the entire process, are you sure that don't using web workers it's the same thing even with big files ?

Comment: YAY! I resolved using php://input!!! ..anyway, thank you :)

Comment: What a mess! Anyway, if you found the problem, either delete the question or write an answer for it. Happy new year to you, too.

Comment: why is a mess ? (sorry for my bad english...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved reading file from php://input with this code:

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
$fp = fopen($target, "w");

while ($data = fread($putdata, 16384)) {
    fwrite($fp, $data);
}

fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
```

In this way, I don't need to write the HTTP headers of the multipart/form-data